# Why do I get "this perl hasn't been configured and built properly for the threads module to work"?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am not a Perl programmer. I was just asked to install a Perl program and followed only the instruction given to me. And I got the following error:

> This `perl` hasn't been configured and built properly for the threads
>   module to work.  (The 'useithreads' configuration option hasn't been
>   used.)
>
> Having threads support requires all of Perl and all of the XS modules
>   in the Perl installation to be rebuilt, it is not just a question of
>   adding the threads module.  (In other words, threaded and non-threaded
>   Perls are binary incompatible.)
>
> If you want to the use the threads module, please contact the people
>   who built your Perl.

How to do I fix this error? I am using hostgator dedicated server - Linux.

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly compile your own `perl` binary.  Look to building your own with thread support.  I'd use [perlbrew](http://www.perlbrew.pl/) .  In this way you won't affect the current installation in any way.

Answer (score 4):

Your program is likely using automake to build/configure its source. And since you mentioned having an HG dedicated server, chances are you're running CentOS. It's worth attempting this workaround:

1. Use a text editor to open file
   /usr/share/automake-1.11/Automake/Config.pm
2. Search or locate line: our $perl_threads = 1;
3. Change 1 to 0 so it looks like this: our $perl_threads = 0;
4. Re-run the installation steps for your scripts

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The program you're trying to install evidently uses the threads module, which the version of Perl you have doesn't support. I see three options for you:

- Tell the person who gave you the program that you need a version that doesn't use threads.
- Tell your hosting provider that you need a different Perl binary. (This is what the error message tells you to do.)
- Run the program somewhere else, on a system that has a compatible Perl.

Comment: No need to bother the hosting company if you can install perlbrew.